IsNumeric function is not working when the value is "0"
I have this JavaScript function in my Razor page to check if the value is numeric.
When a "0" is passed to this function, it will return as false. I have tested the expression in other RegEx tester and "0" is a valid match. If the input parameter is "0.0", it will be ok.
Any idea what went wrong? Please advise. Thanks.


function isNumericValid(value) {
  var result = false;
  if (value != "") {
    // up to 12 digits and 10 dec places
    let template = /^-{0,1}\d{1,12}(\.\d{1,10})?$/;

    if (template.test(value))
      result = true;
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(isNumericValid("0"))
console.log(isNumericValid(0))
console.log(isNumericValid("0.0"))
console.log(isNumericValid(0.0))
console.log(isNumericValid(1234.10))




Works for me (DevTools console): the first test case returns true. If you mean the second case, passing a literal zero, then that is because the length condition fails (that condition is unnecessary because the regex does not match an empty string).

Welcome to JavaScript. You can regard to == and != not as "equal" and "unequal", but "[not] similar to". And false, an empty array, and the number 0 are all similar to an empty string in their "nothingness" in different types, so they are considered similar. Which is why 0 != "" is false. The easiest fix is to get rid of the check since your regex doesn't fit the empty string anyway.

Please don't use tags that are not relevant. This code has nothing to do with ASP.NET Core or Razor Pages.

Is there a reason for not just using isNaN function? This will sense other number formats which maybe isn’t desired??

It's because value != "" returns false.
Replace with not exact equals value !== "" or value != null or value.length > 0 (depends on your usecase)

@RyanOng you can find more informations about type coercion here : https://javascript.info/comparison#strict-equality

The culprit is clear (the input value should be stringified).
You function can be reduced to one line:


console.log(`isNumericValid("0"): ${isNumericValid("0")}`);
console.log(`isNumericValid(0): ${isNumericValid(0)}`);
console.log(`isNumericValid("0.0"): ${isNumericValid("0.0")}`);
console.log(`isNumericValid(0.0): ${isNumericValid(0.0)}`);
console.log(`isNumericValid(1234.10): ${isNumericValid(1234.10)}`);
console.log(`isNumericValid("-1234.10"): ${isNumericValid("-1234.10")}`);
console.log(`isNumericValid(-1234.10): ${isNumericValid(-1234.10)}`);
console.log(`isNumericValid(-1234): ${isNumericValid(-1234)}`);
console.log(`isNumericValid(100000000000n): ${isNumericValid(100000000000n)}`);
console.log(`isNumericValid(-100000000000n): ${isNumericValid(-100000000000n)}`);

function isNumericValid(value) {
  return /^-{0,1}\d{1,12}(\.\d{1,10})?$/.test(String(value).trim());
}
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}




The  value != "" returns false on a 0 (but not on a "0") because of the != operator, which performs type coercion
Add a toString and use !== not strictly equal


function isNumericValid(value) {
  var result = false;
  value = value.toString().trim();
  if (value !== "") {
    // up to 12 digits and 10 dec places
    let template = /^-{0,1}\d{1,12}(\.\d{1,10})?$/;

    if (template.test(value))
      result = true;
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(isNumericValid("0"))
console.log(isNumericValid(0))
console.log(isNumericValid("0.0"))
console.log(isNumericValid(0.0))
console.log(isNumericValid(1234.10))



